# Can I install lapack and blas using mac port/homebrew/fink

Tags: lapack

Depserately trying to make compilation of lapackpp working while it keeps saying cannot find Lapack and Blas. I am wondering whether if there is a way to install Lapack/Blas easily using Macport/Home Brew/Fink or anything other package managers. I am very frustrated and desperate on that and wasted two whole days.....

Answer (score 1):

Installing them is not a big deal, just download them and make them. Their makefiles are easy to read. Of course, I think the easiest way to use lapack and blas is to use the library provided by the system itself. For example, you can compile/link your file in the following way:

> **gfortran  -o a.out  main.f90 -framework Accelerate**